# Unity C#: Value Slider Works But Text Wont Change

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, text

Im working on a game and trying to get my health system working. I made a function which changes a slider depending on your current health which works and there's also a text which should display current health and max health in the following format: "current / max" however it doesn't. Im using the same value in the slider and the text and don't know where it went wrong. Could someone take a look at my code and tell me where I made a mistake?

The error messages that show up are:

Assets\playerMovement.cs(28,19): error CS1061: 'HealthBar' does not contain a definition for 'SetMaxHealth' and no accessible extension method 'SetMaxHealth' accepting a first argument of type 'HealthBar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

Assets\playerMovement.cs(50,19): error CS1061: 'HealthBar' does not contain a definition for 'SetHealth' and no accessible extension method 'SetHealth' accepting a first argument of type 'HealthBar' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int moveSpeed;

    public int maxHealth;
    public int currentHealth;

    public Slider healthSlider;

    public Text HealthText;

    public HealthBar healthBar;

    public void SetMaxHealth(int health)
    {
        healthSlider.maxValue = maxHealth;
        healthSlider.value = health;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    
    
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        HealthText.text = currentHealth + " / " + healthSlider.maxValue;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            TakeDamage(20);
        }

        void TakeDamage(int damage) {
            currentHealth -= damage;

            
        

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);


        }

        if (currentHealth > maxHealth) {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
        }

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0f);

        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `should display current health and max health in the following format: "current / max" however it doesn't.` ... Well what you show us are some compiler errors so you code can not even be compiled nor run ... so how should the text change if you can't even press play? ^^ Could you add your `HealthBar` code? Otherwise it is a bit hard for us to look at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have set your variables as int but you are using them as a string that normally should give you a error/exception

```
HealthText.text = currentHealth.ToString() + " / " + healthSlider.maxValue.ToString();
```

also why are you making a function inside another function

this is your code. Look inside the update function (i show you where i mean by putting  > in front of the line) it contains a void method that is a error

```
void Update()
{

    HealthText.text = currentHealth + " / " + healthSlider.maxValue;

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
        TakeDamage(20);
    }

   > void TakeDamage(int damage) {
   >     currentHealth -= damage;

        
    

  >  healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);


  >  }

    if (currentHealth > maxHealth) {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0f);

    transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Well, it actually told you: the `HealthBar` does not contain definitions for `SetMaxHealth` nor `SetHealth`. Notice the capitalization, it is important in the C# naming.

If you need more help, give us `HealthBar` MonoBehaviour code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28585304)

Comment: @NinoFiliu Actually it does provide the answer for the problem as it is stated. It also describes probably root cause - the capitalization or misspelling. I understand the problem statement is of low quality, but this may still point the OP in the right direction. As the OP cannot vote comment as solving their issue (and as I am a bit tired of asking "Can you write your comment as answer so I can accept"), this is the reason I decided to write this as answer instead.

Comment: @NinoFiliu As proof of what I am saying, the newest question from Unity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66771887/how-do-i-make-an-api-request-in-a-static-utilities-class-in-unity  - the comment should clearly be the answer. Why are some people over here afraid of writing answers...? :-)